# Getting an error updating to Minecraft for Windows 10. What can I do?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I keep getting this error:

> Error! It looks like we've temporarily run out of gift codes for Minecraft for Windows 10. Don't worry though, more codes should be on their way. Please check back later!

How long do I wait for this? What can I do?

Comment: This appears to be a relatively new issue. There is a forum thread and reddit about this, and it seems that there is nothing you can really do for now.

Comment: @TimmyJim - it may be worth expanding that into an answer if you can.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few posts online that are fairly new in age discussing this issue, such as [this one on the Minecraft Forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/windows-10-support/2875911-no-free-copy-error) and a [Reddit post](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/7ifmg9/so_apparently_mojang_has_ran_out_of_gift_codes/).  An additional Minecraft Forum one can be found [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/windows-10-support/2876561-no-gift-codes-minecraft-windows-10) as well.

As the error suggests, you will likely just have to wait for time being. You can also try contacting [Mojang support](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new) which was suggested in the forum posts. During the holiday season, I can understand how they ran out of codes. That being said, I do find it rather odd that there was a limited amount.

Since this is the Windows 10 edition, it seems [Mojang suggests](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2064007-minecraft-for-windows-10) you actually contact [Xbox support](https://support.xbox.com/contact-us#4:1:2).

Comment: I actually did contact Mojang, and they are trying to move around the question..which is stupid.. I asked why and how they ran out of codes, they didn't reply. I asked when they will get some codes. they didn't reply. they told me go to Xbox for help since my purchase was thru Windows store and Xbox, which is WASN'T. it was thru them, Mojang. I even sent them my receipt, then they had a completely different person start emailing me back.. I just emailed him back asking why they can't just send me my win 10 code thru email and also asked when they will be getting codes again. waiting on a reply